# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Membership number.(Anonymous function)

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am struggling to make the "anything as a rule" approach work with CodeIgniter 3:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule

I am using the below array as the rule:

```
array(
    'required',
    array('memnum_unique', array($this->form_validation, 'memnum_unique'))
)
```

Then, I have the function defined as follows:

```
public function memnum_unique()
{
    $memno = $this->CI->input->post('membership_number');
    $exists = $this->CI->votes_model->get_field_unique('membership_number', $memno, true);
    if (!empty($exists))
    {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('memnum_unique', 'The membership number has to be unique. This one has already voted.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Under normal circumstances, I will use `is_unique` rule, but the above function is trimmed down and contains more validation criteria, so I have to use it this way.

The function is called - I can verify that. The `if (!empty($exists))...` part executes, but somehow I still get the error message

`Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Membership number.(Anonymous function)`

The form field generation code is set up like this in my "core" module:

```
public function generate_field($id, $label, $rules, $val = '')
{
    $out = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'validation' => array(
            'field' => $id,
            'label' => $label,
            'rules' => $rules
        ),
        'value' => $val
    );
    return $out;
}
```

It is created like this:

```
$data['fields']['add_member_membership_number'] = $this->core->generate_field('membership_number', 'Membership number', $this->validation_rules['add_member_membership_number']);
```

First, it is not an anonymous function, secondly, it executes, and I think I have everything correct, so why is this not working?

Comment: I managed to make it work by moving the function from my form validation class to the local class. Even though this solves the immediate problem, this is a crappy solution, so still looking for a proper answer, if anyone has something I can try :-) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I ran in to this exact issue, but it is actually addressed in the CodeIgniter documentation: [CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callable-use-anything-as-a-rule).

> Of course, since a Callable rule by itself is not a string, it isn’t a rule name either. That is a problem when you want to set error messages for them. In order to get around that problem, you can put such rules as the second element of an array, with the first one being the rule name:

With this example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        array(
                'required',
                array('username_callable', array($this->users_model, 'valid_username'))
        )
);
```

Comment: I am following the guide. I am doing it the way the manual says.

Comment: If you are defining the "memnum_unique" method in MY_Form_validation, you should be able to just use "required|memnum_unique" in your validation rules setup.